# emberjs #each helper not producing any output even though the template was rendered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

Though the "posts/index" template is rendering, the emberjs #each helper inside the template does not produce any output. this is the **jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxWzu/**

I have tried this:

```
{{#each  post in content}}
 <p> {{post.title}} </p>
<p>{{#linkTo 'posts.post' post}} {{post.body}}  {{/linkTo}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

and this

```
{{#each controller}}
 <p>{{title}} </p>
 <p>{{#linkTo 'posts.post' post}} {{body}}  {{/linkTo}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `EmBlog.Post.find()` in your `model` method for `EmBlog.PostsIndexRoute`.

```
EmBlog.PostsIndexRoute  = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
     return  EmBlog.Post.find();
  }
...
```

Also, you don't need to call `setupController` in either of your routes.  The way you called it is the default in Ember.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/rxWzu/1/)

Comment: thanks @c4p for the answer. Is there a reason why the if /else block did not work, since the else block contained 'return  EmBlog.Post.find();'

Comment: Is `.all()` the correct method for a ember-data model?  In the documentation (http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-models/) it looks like you should use `find()` to get all objects from the model. Also, in your code the `isLoaded` was always returning true so the else was never executed.